# Raster calculation in R

Tags: r

I have two files from these website:
https://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/data/set/gpw-v4-population-count-rev11/data-download

And a shapefile of China from these website
https://gadm.org/download_country_v3.html

I would like to compute the difference between the raster population layers, that I can show a map where each pixel represents the change in the population in China.

I used this code

```
library(raster)
library(sf) 
library(tmap)

p_15 <- terra::rast("gpw-v4-population-count-rev11_2015_2pt5_min_tif/gpw_v4_population_count_rev11_2015_2pt5_min.tif")
p_20 <- terra::rast("gpw-v4-population-count-rev11_2020_2pt5_min_tif/gpw_v4_population_count_rev11_2020_2pt5_min.tif")
CHN <- sf::read_sf("gadm36_CHN_shp/gadm36_CHN_1.shp")
CHN <- sf::st_transform(CHN, crs="epsg:4490")|> terra::vect()
p_15<- terra::project(p_15,'EPSG:4490')
p_20 <- terra::project(p_20,'EPSG:4490')
p_15_crop <- terra::crop(p_15, CHN)
p_20_crop <- terra::crop(p_20, CHN)
p_15_mask <- mask(p_15_crop, CHN)
p_20_mask <- mask(p_2_crop, CHN)
```

The code above everything works fine.

Now I used overlay from the raster package to calculate the difference between the population layers to show the change in each pixel.

I gave these code

```
diff1520 <- overlay(p_15_mask, p_20_mask, fun=function(x,y){return(y-x)})
```

But I got the error message method not applicable??? What is wrong with the code?

By the way, I also used geodata package, but did not solve my problem

Comment: Have you tried `diff1520 <- p_20_mask - p_15_mask`?

Comment: duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/444464/raster-calculation-in-r/444470#444470

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply subtracting the objects will work. But if you still want to apply a function to a `SpatRaster`, you can use `terra::lapp`, which is equivalent to `raster::overlay`. The main difference is that you have to combine the layers first.

```
library(terra)

p_mask <- c(p_15_mask, p_20_mask)
diff1520 <- lapp(p_mask, fun=function(x,y){return(y-x)})
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because you created your masks with `terra`. So the masks are `SpatRast` objects and you tried to use the `overlay()` function from `raster` and that only works with `raster` objects.

You can do what you want with

```
diff1520 <- p_20_mask - p_15_mask
```

That's the basic `terra` way.